# How can I get and assign the return value from MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, call, declare

I have the next stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getUserIdByLogin`(userId VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT id FROM `userdata` WHERE login = userId;
END
```

I want to declare a new variable `@tmp` for e.g. and do smth to this:

```
SET @tmpValue = CALL getUserIdByLogin("someLogin");
```

But it doesn't work.

If just to call:

```
CALL getUserIdByLogin("someLogin");
```

Then I would see results, but I need to declare the results in the variable ( of array type ).

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getUserIdByLogin`(
   userId VARCHAR(255),
   OUT idout int
)
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO idout FROM `userdata` WHERE login = userId;
END
```

then

```
SET @id = 0;
CALL getUserIdByLogin("someLogin",  @id);
SELECT @id;
```

Comment: you have that comma in your second block, but no second argument.  was that intentional?  I don't touch on this area of mysql very often